# windowsoftinputmode 12

Tags: android

Нужно определить какое значение `windowSoftInputMode` имеет значение 12. Не могу найти исходник этого класса с константами

Comment: Уточните систему измерения. 0x0000000c(16) = 12(10) или 0x00000012(16) = 18(10)?

Comment: @zTrap, Я не знаю :) онлайн декомпилер jadx мне вернул манифест с этим числом. Именно 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING = 48 (0x00000030)

SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN = 32 (0x00000020)

SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE = 16 (0x00000010)

SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED = 0 (0x00000000)

SOFT_INPUT_IS_FORWARD_NAVIGATION = 256 (0x00000100)

SOFT_INPUT_MASK_ADJUST = 240 (0x000000f0)

SOFT_INPUT_MASK_STATE = 15 (0x0000000f)

SOFT_INPUT_MODE_CHANGED = 512 (0x00000200)

SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN = 3 (0x00000003)

SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE = 5 (0x00000005)

SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN = 2 (0x00000002)

SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNCHANGED = 1 (0x00000001)

SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNSPECIFIED = 0 (0x00000000)

SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE = 4 (0x00000004)
```

[Источник.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING)